# My custom cell's label size will not change, even to a hard coded value. What could be preventing this?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The block of code below, which alters the lblBody's frame size seems to be having zero effect on my UITableViewCells.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChatCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ChatCellTableView
    //cell.lblBody.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleHeadline)
    cell.lblBody.text = msgSections[indexPath.section].msg[indexPath.row].text
    cell.lblUsername.text = msgSections[indexPath.section].msg[indexPath.row].username
    cell.lblTime.text = msgSections[indexPath.section].msg[indexPath.row].time

    cell.lblBody.frame.size.height = 900
    cell.lblBody.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    return cell
}
```

When I build and run my app, my UITableViewCell's labels are the exact same size as they are in the storyboard editor. I already removed all constraints with the "clear constrains" command, but for some reason my uilabels still set their size based off of the storyboard.

I set the text color to an ugly green just as a sanity check. My uilabel's colors are green, their text is proper, everything but the label's size seems to be effected.

I need this because the array which returns the text to be shown in the UILable also contains the precise width and height the labels will need to work properly.

**UPDATE:**

Another curious thing I've found is that in RAM the heights of my lblBody's are correct when I print the following:

```
    print("THE CURRENT HEIGHT: ")
    print(cell.lblBody.frame.size.height)
    return cell
```

When I build and run the app and scroll through the cells, I get the following output:

```
THE CURRENT HEIGHT: 
900.0
THE CURRENT HEIGHT: 
900.0
THE CURRENT HEIGHT: 
900.0
THE CURRENT HEIGHT: 
900.0
```

So it looks like the height is being properly set within the UILabel's properties, but I don't see UILabels with the height of 900. All of my UILabel's sizes are the same as they appear in the story board editor. Reloading/refreshing the tableview's data does not fix the issue here.

Answer (score 3):

The actual drawing of your cell occurs after `cellForRowAtIndexPath` occurs. To have control after bounds have been set, I would suggest you take a look at modifying the label within the `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method.

Comment: My cell sizes are perfect. The problem is with the UILabels that are within the cells. The height of the cells are set by a pre-calculated CGSize value which are calculated before the table even loads, but the height of the labels will not follow. I can use auto-layout as a work around, but auto layout is buggy after the height of the cells reach a certain point.

Comment: My apologies, misunderstood your question. Changed answer.